# How to set in row selection number of taps

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, touch-event

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            CBCharacteristic characteristic = this._characteristics [indexPath.Row];
            this.CharacteristicSelected (this, new CharacteristicSelectedEventArgs (characteristic));


            NSSet touches = new NSSet();
            UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;


                if (touch != null) {
                    if (touch.TapCount == 1) {

                        Console.WriteLine("1");
                        }


                    }

                    if (touch.TapCount == 2) {
                    Console.WriteLine("2");
                }


            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);

        }
```

What goes wrong?

the tap code is doing nothing...

If I delete or no the app don't count the taps!

I tap 1 time, nothing is show on the output, if I tap 2 the same...

Comment: step through the code and check if `touch` is not null

Comment: You can not get `touch` in `RowSelected` method as at the moment when `RowSelected` method will be called the touch action will be already finished